# actionscript process time delay?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I wanted to know how i would be able to make a tween wait a few extra seconds before it is carried out? MY CODE BELOW:

```
  btn_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, about_navigate);

    function about_navigate(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
        topbarTween.yoyo();
        //how to make the below tween wait 2 seconds before it is carried out   
        btmTween.yoyo();
        }
```

I am new to AS3 so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using the native tweening library? or a third party one like TweenLite/Tweener/Gtween?

Comment: i am using the native library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the Native `Tween` class has a built in delay method (like most third party solutions do - Though someone please correct me if I'm mistaken).

What you can do is use `flash.utils.setTimeout` or a `Timer`.

```
function about_navigate(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    topbarTween.yoyo();
    setTimeout(btmTween.yoyo,2000);
}
```

Comment: just a quick question how would the code be for this:                                                            var myRotationTween:Tween = new Tween(content_mc, "rotation",Elastic.easeOut, content_mc.rotation, content_mc.rotation-90, 3, true);
                                                       setTimeout(myRotationTween,500);